# Draw evenly spaced lines in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to draw evenly spaced vertical lines in python ? 
I'm trying to draw vertically lines evenly spreaded on a graph, I'm trying to divide the range of domian by the length of the array to get evenly spaced vertical lines, I'm wondering is there any other way to do this ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array = [2,3,1,5,7,9]

xMin = -30
xMax = 30
plt.ylim(0,30 )
plt.xlim(xMin,xMax)

factor = (xMax - xMin)/len(array)

for i in array:
   plt.plot((xMin,xMin),(0,i),'-k')
   xMin+= factor

plt.show()
```

PS.The numbers in the array means the value for Y-axis
[image]

Comment: You can use built-in commands for grids since you're using matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/pylab_examples/axes_props.html

Comment: What's the problem? Your example does what you said it should.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Hi, I'm just wondering is there any other way to do this, since I found that the first line is overlapped with the Y-axis

Comment: @whitefall Try increasing your xlimits: `plt.xlim(-40, 40)`.  BTW, you're not looking for a bar chart, are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; import numpy as np
array, xmin, xmax, ymax = [2,3,1,5,7,9], -30, 30, 30
plt.ylim(0,ymax)
[plt.axvline(v, ymax=array[i]/ymax, c='k', lw=1) for i, v in enumerate(np.linspace(xmin,xmax,len(array)))];
```

[image]

Comment: Hi so sorry for the confusion, the numbers in the array means the value of Y axis, and I’m trying to distribute the lines evenly on the graph

Comment: Thank your for your answer  btw !! :)

Comment: It's a bit strange that you're using a list comprehension for this. (Especially since the list is thrown away immediately upon construction.) Also, I would avoid the use of semicolons; they're not pythonic.

Comment: Yes, it is probably more readable to do a normal for loop. I use the semi colon to suppress the output of the return value (a list of Line2D objects). I'm in an ipython shell. Could have done this as well: ```_ = [plt.axvline(v, ymax=array[i], c='k', lw=1) for i, v in enumerate(np.linspace(xmin,xmax,len(array)))]```